# Unit Test Subscribe function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-router

Is there a way to check if router is navigating to the desired page if getToken() is returning a value.

```
onSubmit(value: Authentication){
    this.authenticateService.getTokenFromServer(value).subscribe(v => {
        if(this.tokenService.getToken()){
            this.router.navigate([Config.videoPage]);
        }
        console.log(this.tokenService.getToken());
    });
}
```

Unit test I've tried

```
 it('redirect to video if token set', () => {
    let component = fixture.componentInstance;
    let navigateSpy = spyOn((<any>component).router, 'navigate');

    component.onSubmit({name: 'Abc', password: '123'});
    expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/video']);
  });
```

Comment: Its obvious that it will. Don't test the framework, test your code.

Comment: I agree with @AluanHaddad. Don't test the GUI behavior, you can check it directly on your browser. If you don't have token you don't be routed. It's possible to test it but the GUI is not "stable", tomorrow the route can be change and the day after tomorrow too... do you want change your test each time?

Comment: I don't get what you mean that "tomorrow the route can be changed". It cannot, when submitting you will either go to /video route, or you wont. Nothing will change.

Comment: @Fig that's not necessarily true. For example, you may have a future requirement such that only certain users can view certain videos which leads to the introduction of a workflow where you transition to an intermediate state allowing the user to request access without leaving the context of the current screen. I've used video sites that behave that way. This doesn't mean you should over engineer planning for the future, but it does mean that testing this specific coupling between your component and route is not advantageous.